# How can i test 'auth().signInWithCredential' in firebase/app?

Tags: firebase, react-native, jestjs, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am writing test code using firebase/auth and google login with react-native

But, there are always bug in my test code

my UI component is below.

```
import { GoogleSignin } from "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin";
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";

 let userInfo;
    try {
      userInfo = await GoogleSignin.signIn();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
    const googleCredential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(userInfo.idToken);

let testPromise;
    try {
      testPromise = await auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
    } catch (error) {
      // In real code environment, there are no problem.
      // But, In my test environment, the engine of the code always occur error in here
      console.error(error);
    }
```

The error message is below.

```
 console.error
      TypeError: (0 , _auth.default) is not a function
```

my mocking part of the test code is below

```
jest.mock("@react-native-firebase/auth", () => {
  return {
    GoogleAuthProvider: {
      credential: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ providerId: "fakeProviderId", secret: "fakeSecret", token: "fakeToken" }),
    },
    signInWithCredential: jest.fn(),
  };
});
```

Comment: Where is `auth()` coming from? Can you share complete code so we can see the imports.

Answer (score 0):

some tricks are in there.

i think the way i suggests is not best practice.
but, you can do this problem like this.

```
In react component...
import auth from "@react-native-firebase/auth";
import { firebase } from "@react-native-firebase/auth"; << KEY POINT
```

```
test component...
const mockedFbAuth = jest.fn();
jest.mock("@react-native-firebase/auth", () => {
  return {
    firebase: {
      auth: jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
        signInWithCredential: mockedFbAuth.mockReturnValue({
          additionalUserInfo: {
            profile: {
              email: "fakeCredentialEmail",
              name: "fakeCredentialName",
            },
          },
        }),
      })),
    },
  };
});
```

above this way, i can solve my problem!